# Java , Jasper PDF Export, combine OpenSansEmoji with DejaVuSans

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, emoji

Well, i am trying to export a single PDF which will contain a text field holding both normal Latin characters and emojis. The text is inputted by the user , through an html form , in which i can confirm that the emojis are being rendered properly in the Browser, even if i re-fetch them from Java side(thought that the characters might be corrupted). Unfortunately, i still haven't got the expected result , although i tried following the steps from community.jaspersoft.

What i tried :

Exported a single jar containing all the fonts(ttfs) inside, from JasperSoft Studio , compiled the jrxml and included both in the classpath, but still the emojis are coming as spaces in the PDF.

The ttf i used for the emojis has been downloaded from this [github link](https://github.com/MorbZ/OpenSansEmoji) and the dejavu from [here](https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/)

What i haven't tried :

- Combine all the fonts into a single ttf ( is that feasible ? )
- Export the text as raw image rather than text field inside the jrxml ( again not sure if that is feasible )

So the main question is whether is that feasible or not , because i can see others looking for the same issue without a proper answer and if not , are there any other things i could try ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a file *fonts/fontsfamily[someRandomNumber].xml* in the JAR with TTF font exported from JasperSoft Studio. Look into the file and make sure that there is `pdfEmbedded` set on `true` and `pdfEncoding` set on `Identity-H`.

For example in my case there wasn't `pdfEncoding` element and then emoji symbols were rendered as spaces but when I added `<pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>` emoji symbols were rendered correctly.

Here is an example of that XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>
    <fontFamily name="OpenSansEmoji">
        <normal>fonts/OpenSansEmoji/OpenSansEmoji.ttf</normal>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <exportFonts/>
    </fontFamily>
</fontFamilies>
```

Or you can do it in JasperSoft Studio by editing of font family properties and then new JAR export:
[image: JasperSoft Studio - Font Family properties]

Comment: tried that as well , indeed it must be applied , but still it will not render characters as     but only ☺️. Guessing there might be an issue with the 2 / 4 byte encoding ? ? So the font ttf i am using is not the proper one ? ?

Comment: ReadMe on the OpenSansEmoji GitHub page says: _All symbols are in monochrome._
There is no problem with 3 byte - I tried penguin icon with code U+1F427 for example using `new String(Character.toChars(0x1f427))` and it worked fine.

Comment: Yeap i tried that as well (but cant do it for all of them) and also tried to include another emoji ttf , from [here](https://github.com/jslegers/emoji-icon-font) , but still dont got them coloured